# How to serialize a NodeSeq?

Tags: string, scala, serialization

I need to serialize a `NodeSeq`, but I can't find a clean way of doing so.

I can convert a `NodeSeq` to a String, which is serializable, then reconstruct the `NodeSeq` at the other end using `Unparsed`, but this seems unnecessarily hackish to me.

Is there a better way to serialize a `NodeSeq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using a `NodeBuffer` instead of a `NodeSeq`.